# Send Ctrl+f python selenium chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am able to use some keys like <kbd>Tab</kbd>

```
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

But not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>

```
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL +'f')
```

I also tried using xpath `find_element_by_xpath &` `send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'f')` but still not working

Comment: Hey did `ActionChains` worked out for you or you found any other solution? It would be better if you post it..

Comment: Nope, its din't worked out so i ditched selenium & used web scrapping for my case.

Answer (score 3):

You shall try by using `action_chains` in selenium webdriver

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
#
# Your code
#
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
ActionChains(browser).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "f").perform()
```

Comment: @ankushpatial, Can you please let me know what you have tried?

Comment: Didn't the search box open for you? or else do you want to enter any text in that search box?

Comment: Nope.... no Search box is opening.
and yeah, after this, i want to enter text in search box

Comment: Which version of webdriver you are using?

Comment: its ChromeDriver 2.29.461591

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I have not known the answer before. I searched and run code using selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains but failed.

Then after more research, I was suggested to use pyautogui library. I don’t know how, but it worked for me… you can try the code.

```
# Import necessary libraries

from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui

# to get the broswer

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Windows\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")


# code to perform ctrl+F

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'f')
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to time.sleep(1) to wait for my pdf document to load in the browser just before running the hotkey ctrl+f function, then everything worked smoothly.