# Python Selenium - Search data table values in website

Tags: python, selenium, web, datatable

I am doing a project where I need to search data table values in a webpage. My data table iS: `['FT 202003/69362', 'FT 202003/62581', 'FT 202003/4664', 'FT 201903/215090', 'FT 201903/197043']`, so, for each value, I need to search same value in website and click in a button that belong to that value (button is "Obter documentos". Any ideas?

Website page
[[image: Website page[1]]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43885246/6490744   try this

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added the website page screenshot to original post. Do you still think I can do it that way? I am not understanding how...

Comment: instead you can get all buttons - loop through - check if your your any of your text is present, click

Comment: I already tried but it didn't work... Can you please send me code?